# Can I split my 30kg check-in luggage into multiple suitcases?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, germany, bookings, turkish-airlines

I am travelling with Turkish Airlines, from Berlin to Istanbul, and I am allowed 30kg of luggage or check-in. However, in the booking it doesn't mention the number of luggage items that I am allowed. I tried calling the sales office but they put me on hold multiple times and the calls then randomly ended.

Therefore, I am curious if anyone knows any more about this situation?

Comment: The baggage calculator site implies this is total weight of 30 kg, not per-piece. Furthermore, it asks if you need more baggage and allows you to enter a single numerical kg measurement. If it were per-piece, then the site would be incapable of pricing more than 2 pieces of baggage. Therefor I would expect you get a total allotment of 30kg checked, and can pay additional for more checked baggage. https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/any-questions/free-baggage/baggage-calculator/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Airlines generally use one of two models for checked baggage allowances - either a "piece" model or a "weight" model.  Some airlines will use the same model for all flights, whilst others will use one model for some flights, and the other for other flights.

Under a "piece" model you are limited to a set number of pieces of checked baggage.  Each piece will have a maximum weight, but the weight of one piece will not impact your allowance for any other piece. If your allowance was 2 pieces, each up to 23kg and one piece was 10kg, then the other piece would still be limited to 23kg.

With a piece model, excess baggage charges generally apply if you want to check more bags that your limit, OR if any of the bags are over the allowed per-bag weight.

Under a "weight" model, your allowance is based on the total weight of all of your bags - with no general limit to the number of bags that can be checked. In your example you have a 30kg limit, which would allow you to check a single bag weighing 30kg, OR one bag weighting 10kg and another weighing 20kg, OR three bags weighting 10kg each.

With a weight model, excess baggage charges generally only apply if your total weight is over the allowed weight.

Specifically for Turkish airlines, the use both "piece" and "weight" models depending on the region of the flight.  You can find details of the [regions for the piece model](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-tr/any-questions/traveling-with-pets/fees-for-carrying-pets/regions-operated-with-piece-baggage-application/index.html) and the [regions for the weight model](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-tr/any-questions/traveling-with-pets/fees-for-carrying-pets/regions-operated-with-kg-application/index.html) on their website.  An easier way to check is instead to use the [baggage calculator](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/any-questions/free-baggage/baggage-calculator/) available on their website which will tell you the exact model and limitations for a specific flight.

As you've stated, Berlin to Istanbul uses the "weight" model and allows 30kg of weight for Economy passengers, so you will be allowed have multiple bags, up to a total weight of 30kg.

(Note that the links to the TK website above include "traveling-with-pets" in the URL itself, however this appears to be an error as these links have nothing to do with traveling with pets.  Anyone that's used the TK website in the past will know that issues like this are not uncommon!)

Comment: Out of interest, in the weight model, is there generally still a specified maximum number of pieces or minimum weight per piece? I'd imagine that with a total weight allowance of 30kg it would not be possible to check 30 pieces of luggage with 1kg each.

Comment: @Emil wait, I can’t just fly with 30 individually wrapped bags of flour?!

Comment: @Doc Thank you for the detailed answer! I checked out the links and you are indeed correct. My flight uses the weight-model so the number of luggage items is not fixed, however the weight of the total luggage is indeed fixed.

Comment: @Tim Customs might be interested in you if you did that.

Comment: @user1937198 I'd almost feel bad for the agent who had to taste-test each individual bag of flour to confirm they were, indeed, flour. (has watched too many cop shows...)

Comment: Don't forget the empty weight of the luggage.  Splitting into a hard suitcase and a soft bag of non-fragile items isn't too bad, but two hard suitcases will eat into the weight allowance.

Comment: Always wondered if you could fill in all the empty space with helium-filled bubble-wrap to reduce the weight - I feel like there's some reason that wouldn't work or somebody would be making a lot of money on that...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman for a 50x40x20 cm luggage, you would gain ~40g if it was completely filled in with helium

Comment: @DarrelHoffman The weight reduction would be minimal- a cubic foot of air weighs about 36g (sorry the mixed units) and you still have to account for the bag and the mass of the helium. BTW, helium is a non-renewable resource so it really should not be used for frivolous purposes. If close, I usually just move any anvils or whatever into my carry-on which is seldom weighed.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Could go with hydrogen, which is even lighter, but I imagine airlines would not be cool with bringing a bag of flammable gas onboard...

Comment: 30kg is quite heavy. Weight limits (like 23 kg) are there to protect the poor workers who have to move the cases. There's a good chance that a single 30kg suitcase wouldn't be allowed, and you actually _need_ to use two suitcases. Obviously check with the airline.

Comment: @gnasher729 I've never found a major airline that doesn't allow bags up to (at least) 32kg. TK specifically does allow single bags up to 32kg

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I actually had a case where my hand luggage was weighed: I was moving back to Europe from Japan on Qatar Airways with 40 kg allowed on my ticket (weight model) and 30 kg extra pre-purchased. I had planned to use another smaller bag as carry-on plus a rucksack as personal item. However, QA only allows ~15 kg of hand luggage (or was it 10?) and I exceeded that by quite a bit ... I guess my stuff looked suspiciously heavy so the agent asked me to weigh. Checked in another bag, paid for extra weight at the airport (and cheated a lot by putting as much as possible on my body).

Answer (score -1):

Good idea is to check with the airline. I could not find precise info on the website of Turkish Airlines, but they say that in case of code sharing the luggage allowance is determined by the company operating the flight. Therefore, in other terms you need to understand whether the flight will be operated by Turkish Airlines themselves or by one of their partners like Lufthansa.
Airlines often combine both "piece" and "weight" models, meaning that the passenger is allowed to take luggage of certain maximum weight packed in a given number of pieces or less. See, for example, luggage allowances at Swiss.